Hsqldb and PostgreSQL string_agg: object not found
My Spring Boot web application uses PostgreSQL v12 for production and h2 v2.1.214 embedded database for unit testing.
It worked well until I have a native query to test.
This query uses the string_agg aggregate function and I don't have to touch this java method.
The error is:
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: STRING_AGG.
Adding "SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX PGS TRUE" in SQL or/and ";sql.syntax_pgs=true" after the Spring datasource url didn't change anything.
Is there a solution (without container)?

H2 supports string_agg, but this exception came from HSQLDB and not from H2.

The difference is not clear for me. In application.properties, spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:agddb; and in pom.xml, h2. However it is an HsqlException.

HSQLDB supports string_agg. Use the latest version 2.7.3. For example SELECT STRING_AGG(LASTNAME, ',' ORDER BY CITY) FROM Customer

@fredt Thanks a lot! The solution was to upgrade HSQLDB. I've deleted all references to h2.

@fredt Yes, 'STRING_AGG' really works in HSQLDB. But I am not able to find this info in any documentation e.g.  https://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html. Maybe there are other features in HSQLDB that are not clearly documented and we can use during junit testing to be more compatible with production DBs like MS SQL/Oracle/PostgreSQL/etc.

@fredt Strange is, that LISTAGG is SQL:2016 standard and is not supported by HSQLDB, but STRING_AGG is supported.

LISTAGG will be supported in the next release.
